# Issue applying Descarte's rule of signs to $y=x^2$.

Tags: polynomials, roots

Descarte's rule of signs for $p(x)=x^n$ for $n>0$, says that there are zero roots in this case. However, we can clearly see that it has 1 root at $x=0$. Could somebody please explain why is the rule not applicable and what other cases one can't use the rule for? Thank you all.

Comment: I believe Descartes' rule of signs is about *strictly positive* real roots, *i.e.* $x \gneq 0$ such that $p(x) = 0$. The root at zero is not strictly positive, and so is not counted by Descartes' rule.

Comment: @Lemmon, thanks for your answer. Although the rule is written in different formats, non of the formats I came across states what you suggested! Thank you.